# How to change `Private Database` to `Public Database` from `Cloudkit` Console?

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit

How to change `Private Database` to `Public Database` from `Cloudkit` Console?

I was working on a project which needs to use database. At the time of creation of the app, along with check `CoreData`, I also checked "Host in `Cloudkit`". Everytime I insert any data into the `CoreData`, It also get inserted into the `cloudkit` automatically with same entity/table name. How ever the type of database in cloudkit is private.
Is there any way to change the database type from private to public from `cloudkit` console. If not  , then is it possible to do the configuration from app side so that the auto created database in `cloudkit` will be public type?

I tried to change the security roles from cloudkit console but that did not solve the issue.

Comment: Do you really want it to be in the public database? That means every user of your app sees the same data and the data is stored in *your* iCloud account.

Comment: yes, I do, I am trying to make a bus seat booking app that needs to see any data updated by any user. I know the other possible way to do it which is creating and fetching `CKRecord` from `CloudKit` but I was trying to make the auto synchronization between CoreData and CloudKit.

Comment: @HangarRash It isn't stored in the developer's iCloud account.  It is stored in a public CloudKit database that is associated with the app developer. There is a free quota, which increases as the installed-base of the app increases, but if that quota is exceeded then the developer needs to pay.

Comment: You can use Core Data against your app's public CloudKit database - See https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10650 However, you need to decide if this is appropriate for your needs; It has limited access control settings and availability on non-Apple platforms